# Marvel API: Using XMLHttpRequest to fetch data

Tags: javascript, api

This is my first time using the Marvel API. I'm trying to show the id, image and series of characters using JavaScript but I don't know how to output this information into my HTML.

Any help?

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=xxx');
  xhr.send();

  console.log('Loading...');
  xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {

    //console.log(xhr.responseText);

    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var resultsLength = data.data.results;

    for (var i = 0; i < resultsLength.length; i++) {

      console.log(resultsLength[i]);
      console.log(resultsLength[i].id);
      console.log(resultsLength[i].name);
      console.log(resultsLength[i].series);

      var id = resultsLength[i].id;
      var nome = resultsLength[i].name;
      var series = JSON.stringify(resultsLength[i].series);

      var ul = document.querySelector('#comics');
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      ul.appendChild(li);

   }

 });

})();
```

Thanks for your answer @Sil Cia. Based in your answer I'm updating my code bellow. Now I can output in the HTML the series information and other ones.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=xxx');
xhr.send();

console.log('Loading...');
xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  var resultsLength = data.data.results;

  for (var i = 0; i < resultsLength.length; i++) {

    var arr = {
      id: resultsLength[i].id,
      nome: resultsLength[i].name,
      series: resultsLength[i].series
    }

    var seriesStr = '';
    if (arr.series && arr.series.items) {
      for (var x = 0; x < arr.series.items.length; x++) {
        seriesStr += '<a href="#">' + arr.series.items[x].name + '</a>';
      }
    }

    var ul = document.querySelector('#comics');
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    var id = document.createElement('span');
    var nome = document.createElement('span');
    var series = document.createElement('span');

    id.innerHTML = arr.id;
    nome.innerHTML = arr.nome;
    series.innerHTML = seriesStr;

    li.appendChild(id);
    li.appendChild(nome);
    li.appendChild(series);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="comics"></ul>
```

Comment: try using appendChild instead of textContent at li.textContent = img; like li.appendChild(img);

Comment: @JayLane sorry I change my code

Comment: Why downvote my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, right now in the series variable, you have an object that looks like this:

{available: 3, collectionURI: "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334/series", items: Array(3), returned: 3}

What you want to do it to gain access to the items array inside this object, which contains the series name.

so in your code at line:

```
var series = JSON.stringify(resultsLength[i].series);
```

you can modify with:

```
var seriesName = resultsLength[i].series.items[0].name;
//Note: No need for JSON.stringify here
```

So you are accessing the first item's name in the "items **array**" inside the "series **object**".

The "0" in items[0] should probably be a dynamic value, you will most likely be looping through this items array to display all the series.

Like so:

```
var seriesItems = resultsLength[i].series.items;
//I changed the variable name not to confuse it with the "series" object

if (seriesItems.length > 0) {
//Check to make sure this character has some available series!

    for (var j = 0; j < seriesItems.length; j++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var text = document.createTextNode(seriesItems[j].name);
        li.appendChild(text);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
} 
else {
  var text = document.createTextNode('The series are unavailable!');
  ul.appendChild(text);
}
```

**Don't forget to go change your API Key now that you have published it online!**